# scala delete all files but not directory

Tags: java, scala, file, java.nio.file

I have a directory and subfolder in it.
The directory contains 5 file and one subdirectory.
I need to empty the subfolder and delete 3 files out of 5.

Currently I am using below code which is deleting the file but sub folder is not getting empty.
Please suggest

```
  Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get("src/main/tempDir/doc-topics-new.txt"))
  Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get("src/main/tempDir/new_corpus.mallet"))
  Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get("src/main/tempDir/corpus.mallet"))
  Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get("src/main/tempDir/sub_directory/*"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`better-files`](https://github.com/pathikrit/better-files#file-system-operations) supports deleting all children in directory with `file.clear()` whilst files could be deleted with `file.delete()`. Here is a working example

```
import better.files._

object Hello extends App {
    val subdirectory = file"/path/to/subdirectory"
    subDirectory.clear()

    val file1 = file"/path/to/file1.txt"
    file1.delete()
}
```

where we need the following dependency

```
libraryDependencies += "com.github.pathikrit" %% "better-files" % "3.8.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the files from the subdirectory (but not the directory itself) like this:

```
def deleteOnlyFiles(file: File): Unit = {
  if (file.isDirectory) {
    file.listFiles.foreach(deleteOnlyFiles)
  } else {
     if (file.exists && !file.delete) {
       throw new Exception(s"Unable to delete ${file.getAbsolutePath}")
     }
  }
}
```